# Read json file as javascript variable on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to read data from a json file into JavaScript so it can be used by other functions that are called when a user interacts with the page. I've tried, using jQuery and JS:

```
var products = null;
$.getJSON("products.json", function(data) {
  products = data;
  console.log(data);
});
console.log(products);
```

Which produces, as expected:

```
null
Array [ {…}, {…} ]
```

I understand this is because of the asynchronous nature of the jQuery code execution. I've read into it a bit, but I'm just struggling to wrap my head around how to re-structure my code (coming from pretty much exclusively Python).

This is how I'm seeing it:

```
var products = null;
$.getJSON("products.json", function(data) {
  products = data;
  console.log(data);
});

function do_stuff(){
  // Access the attributes of data and do stuff
}

function do_more_stuff(){
  // Do some more stuff with the data
}
```

I would probably have `do_stuff()` execute when the page body loads, and let's say `do_more_stuff` executes when the user selects something in a dropdown menu. Both need to access the data in products.json. I know there are many examples out there, but I'm just not getting it. How can I re-structure the code to actually work?

Comment: I happened upon this question and I'm happy to tell you that your `This is how I'm seeing it:` code is already the solution you're looking for. The only mistake you seem to be making is you're trying to access `data` when you need to access the external `products` variable instead inside `do_stuff` and `do_more_stuff`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
function get_json(cb) {
    $.getJSON("products.json", function(data) {
      cb(data);
    });  
}

function cb(data) {
    // do stuff here if you want
    console.log(data)
}

get_json(cb)
```

Create a callback function cb (or call it do_stuff if you'd like).  Pass a reference to that function to your async function (get_json).  When the async operation is complete, call your callback function with the data you received.

Comment: Thank you - this was exactly what I needed to see in order to understand!